# Angular 2 -Can not multiply two interpolated values?

Tags: angular

I am attempting to multiply two interpolated values, but I am not having much success. When I attempt to use {{}}*{{}} the values are displayed and no multiplication occurs.  I can see both values, but there is no calculation.

displays 10.00*.20 instead of 20% of 10 which would be 2.00

```
  <tr>
          <td class="table-borderless"  colSpan="4" class="text-right"><b>Total</b></td>
          <td>${{ Items | cartTotal  | number: '.2'}}{{estimate.discount}}</td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `{{ (Items | cartTotal  | number: '.2') * estimate.discount}}` do the trick?

Comment: Exactly, that resolved my issue. Please submit this as answer so I can accept this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiplying the interpolated strings, multiply the expressions and then interpolate:

```
{{ (Items | cartTotal | number: '.2') * estimate.discount}}
```